How to simulate a scenario where an OPC UA client does not receive acknowledgments for Publish requests?
I'm working with OPC UA, using UaExpert as my client connected to an OPC UA server. Here's the sequence of actions I've set up:
The client creates a session with the OPC UA server.
The client then sets up a subscription and adds monitored items.
The client issues a Publish request.
What I'm trying to achieve is a test scenario where the client does not receive an acknowledgment after issuing the Publish request. Is there a way to simulate or configure this behavior?
Any suggestions or tools that could help create this scenario would be greatly appreciated.
